# typescript: Infer tuple value at index from usage

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

How do you infer a Value of a tuple at a specific from usage index.

```
class A<T extends any[]> {
  constructor(public a: T[0]) {

  }
}

// a should be A<[number]>
let a = new A(2)
// but is A<any[]>
```

[This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYzGwE8BtAXQD5oBvAWAChppgB7bCDAJwFdgMXOACgAO3AEYgAlsGhgAXNEQkADGQCUNBgyYBfBnvoMA9EdnQIACxbcQuaGJRx4JbNwC2DzpQYgUGMwC80NgoAO5wggBMasamYtz+kjAIhKTe9EA) is what I am looking for. Is the above described functionality somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explictily specify the type argument which will type-check:

```
const a1 = new A<[number]>(2); // ok
const a2 = new A<[number]>('Oops'); // error
```

Automatically inferring the type like this is not possible, I think. However, if you only care about the first value in the array (as in your example), something like this would be possible:

```
class A<U, T extends [U, ...any[]]> { 
  constructor(public a: U) { }
}

const a = new A(2); // A<number, [number, ...any[]]>
```

Or, sticking with your original definition, you could go through a static factory method:

```
class A<T extends any[]> {
  constructor(public a: T[0]) {
  }

  static create<U>(a: U): A<[U]> { 
    return new A(a);
  }
}

const a = A.create(2); // A<[number]>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Especially the second approch, with the addition of `<U, T extends [U] = [U]>`, was helpful.